# Running cable for a new outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

If putting in a new outlet and junction box behind my TV (it's one of those USB and socket outlets that I'm putting in a box to run wires in the wall). I know I'm supposed to take the wire from the breaker and put it in the new box then run new length back to previous box. But can I use more wire and instead of take it out the old box just run wire back and forth? I don't want to totally tear open the wall, drywall and paint later.

Comment: 2. you don't need to touch neutral, and there's likely no traveler, just a switched hot to the light and a hot from the panel. Just connect both black wires to the dimmer at the two different screws and ground it. You can use most decent newer LED bulbs with it as well, since they are now made to work well with old-school dimmers that used to not play well with LED bulbs of a few years back.

Comment: You have two separate, unrelated questions here. Please [edit] your post to remove one of them, then create a whole new question with it. Since you've taken the tour, you know that you're expected to "accept" an answer to close our your question, and you may get two great answers, one for the first question and one for the second question, and then you cannot accept them both.  It's just how things work 'round here. Heck, you can see even the comment had to be specific to address one of the two questions... Thanks!

Comment: I've reduced your post to one question as FreeMan suggested. We're not a discussion forum (see [ask]). However, your question is not clear to me. What does "back and forth" mean here? Please revise further to clarify.

Comment: FYI, a "gang box" is something crews use to store tools. You have a "junction box". The term "gang" may be used to refer to the number of device spaces in a box, as in "two-gang [junction] box".

Comment: Please clarify "But can I use more wire and instead of take it out the old box just run wire back and forth?" Maybe take a picture, draw on it to show what you mean, then [edit] it into your post. Maybe just a little sketch of what's going on will help.

Comment: "I'm supposed to take the wire from the breaker and put it in the new box then run new length back to previous box." - citation needed. GL ;)

Comment: I didn't know the whole one question thing. But my bad about that. Thank you Dan I'm going to do that tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Also thank you Isherwood I will stop using that term and looking stupid hahaha. And as far has the more wire I basically have a easy shot through two small holes I have already made so can I run wire up to new box and Back down to the old one? I know it sounds dumb but it's kinda far from where the TV is mounted to the outlet. I don't see why this wouldnt be safe but is this safe? Lol (not is it smart, is it safe)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

- Panel -> new -> old

or

- Panel -> old -> new

No functional difference. Keep in mind that the old may be already sending wires off to another receptacle. So you could also have:

- Panel -> old A -> old B and new
- Panel -> new -> old A -> old B

I would say that *generally speaking*, chaining new from old rather than inserting new into the middle of an existing chain will be much easier. That's because the existing wire may be stapled in place or twist & turn in ways that make it impossible (or at least impractical) to route to a new box without tearing open the wall. If you simply add new to old (i.e., a new branch) then at least you know exactly where you'll be going and not necessarily have to tear open any walls. If you do have to tear open walls for the new wire, if you plan it right and your house isn't *too* strange, you should be able to get away with just a few small holes that are easy to patch.

Comment: I have found that, at least for shorter runs, temporarily removing the baseboard and placing new wire under it is faster and neater than tearing up and repairing the wall.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg The devil is in the details. If you have to go across a doorway or to the other side of the room, baseboards don't help. Or if you pull off the baseboards and find there isn't enough room for a cable. But yes, sometimes that will work quite well.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg - that doesn't meet code unless you notch the studs and use protection plates.

Comment: @Mazura Likely true. I've done it for low voltage (phone/network) but never for 120V.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on to respond. But thank you all for your responses.

Comment: So I actually already did it but maybe you could let me know if I did anything wrong

Comment: I wanted to try and better explain the situation here are some drawings of the situation https://imgur.com/gallery/vFcLAIA

Comment: There are basically two issues: 1 - Did you run the wires in a legal manner - i.e., appropriate size/type, properly protected from damage, all connections in accessible junction boxes, etc. and 2 - did you wire all hots together, all neutrals together - which, except for GFCI/receptacles which confuse things, is actually the default way to do things. Can't tell *any* of that from a diagram, but could figure out a lot from actual pictures.

Comment: I definitely wire nutted the live wires and Nuetruals. The pic was more just cause my explanation of what was happening sucked. And I used 14/2 NM. Not sure if that's right but it's pretty close if it's not